# Stereo Enhanced Mono

Tags: amplitude-modulation, vintage, medium-wave

Medium Wave AM in most countries is monophonic. AM stereo was never universally adopted. Given a monophonic signal, how can one create a stereo output?

I know there are some 'tricks' you can play on ears to make the original sound better. Is there something that could be done with phasing that could generate a stereo output? Would some scheme employing delays result in a stereo effect?

In practice, would a DSP solution be superior to an analog one?

Comment: Huh? What *"MW AM in most countries"*?  Most countries don't allow anywhere near MW levels for commercial AM stations.  Here in the US, the highest power AM stations are 50 kW.  That's 20 times less than 1 MW.  Then what's with the annoying formatting of a space before each period and no space after?  I might have been willing to work with you to clarify this question, but when you thumb your nose at us like that, it's just easier to close, downvote and move on.

Comment: How is the question related to power levels? And yes the punctuation is odd, but I didn't even notice it until you pointed it out.

Comment: I believe that by "MW AM" the Original Poster meant "Medium Wave Amplitude Modulated".

Comment: @OlinLathrop MW, or [Medium Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_wave) is what most of the world outside the US calls "AM Radio."

Comment: @dmb: This is yet another example then of why one should not be lazy with abbreviations unless they are *very* common.  Especially considering that in a EE context, "MW" would be "mega-Watts" most of the time.  If it meant "medium wave", then that really should have been spelled out at least the first time.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - "medium wave" is the first hit that comes up if you search on MW Radio. Maybe this is a Europe/US thing, but the abbreviation is extremely well known, and was quite obvious to me from context.

Comment: Compleatly unrelated to AM radio, but try to feed any mono signal though a _stereo_ spring reverb and you will be blown away of the spatial presence of the sound.

Comment: I must agree with @Olin here, Autistic, your otherwise very good English is ruined by your spaces before periods and question marks. You must stop.

Answer (score 3):

It's very doubtful whether it can be done in a satisfactory way that will sound convincing on any program material. Basically you are asking to somehow restore information which has been lost. We can consider various schemes based on splitting the signal into various bands and so on, but the issue is that we are dealing with information sources which do not fall into such bands.

Considering a few "use cases":

1. solo piano. In a naive way, it might be feasible to divide notes by frequency, keeping the lower octaves left, higher to the right, and mid range in between. As an improvement, we might consider trying to keep a note and its related overtones panned in the same place. (But remember that some strings on a real piano vibrate in sympathy, and here the model might break down.)
2. A vocal ensemble. If there are (say) two sopranos left and right, it will be almost impossible to recreate what we might have heard on headphones I think. The information is gone.
3. An orchestra in a semi-reverberant room. The violins are left, celli and basses to the right (noone can hear the violas anyway), and various brass and woodwind somewhere in between. The spectra of the various groups all overlap, and the room reflections add another layer of complexity to the signal. I doubt whether any amount of DSP will do a convincing "mono to stereo" job on this.

It's worth noting that there is one common example of "Stereo synthesised from Mono" which is extremely common; when a multitrack recording, consisting of many (perhaps all) mono sources, is combined to a stereo signal using [pan pot](https://www.eeweb.com/extreme-circuits/pan-pot) circuits. But this is only possible because the mono tracks exist separately to begin with. In other words, information was never lost in the first place, in this scenario, so there is no difficulty in restoring it.

Comment: +1 it is good to get opinions .I suspect that there is no free lunch.I think that a simple analog network will not do much otherwise it would have been implemented .lMaybe a more compluicated scheme will give subjective improvement but not stereo.